# MySQL REPLACE behaves differently than UPDATE if the PRIMARY KEY is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, replace

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repeat_interval` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  KEY `id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON  DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repeat_interval` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `start` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `end` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category`     (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I make a `REPLACE` in the *category* table (one row) then all the entries in the *event* table referencing the modified row in the *category* table will be discarded.

But if I `UPDATE` a row in the *category* table then the entries in the *event* table are left untouched.

Why this behaviour, why when I `REPLACE` something all the entries referencing that column are discarded?

I tried with both `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and the default, same behaviour.

Google couldn't help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have got `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign key, and replace is simply "delete then insert new version" - it seems ON DELETE triggers are fired.

From Mysql Docs:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before  the new row is inserted. See
>   Section 12.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

To workaround this, you will probably want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` insert syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

the behavior of replace is as a delete and re-insert.  this is useful when you are trying to update the primary key.

i presume with the foriegn key relation, you are getting a delete cascade followed by an insert into the table, but without inserts into the foreign table.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have ON DELETE CASCADE. REPLACE deletes the record from `category` table, which then deletes all `event` records assigned to that `category`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run a one-time upgrade script, so my work-around was to:

1. Drop the foreign key constraints
2. Run my "REPLACE INTO" statements
3. Re-add the foreign key constraints

That wouldn't work as a permanent solution in code, but it does work as a quick hack.